# continuous functional in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and let $A: H\rightarrow H$ be linear. Suppose there exists such $B: H\rightarrow H$ that $u(Af,g)=u(f,Bg)$ for any $f,g\in H$ (we denote that $u(-.\cdot)$ is an inner product). Show that $A$ is contiunous.

This excercise seems to be easy but I couldn't find any way to solution.

Comment: You are asking whether the *adjoint* of a *bounded linear operator* is a bounded linear operator. Try an internet search with the keywords in italic.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro boundedness of $A$ or $B$ is not assumed. He is asking whether a globally defined operator with a globally defined adjoint is necessarily continuous.

Comment: Oh sorry I misinterpreted that "such B etc...".

Answer (score 2):

$B$ is also a linear operator. I think you probably demand this anyway, but didn't mention it. In any case this is easy to see.

From $u(Af,g)=u(f,Bg)$ for all $f,g\in H$ you can read off that $A=B^*$, in other words $A$ is the adjoint of an operator. The adjoint of an operator is always a *closed operator*. The *closed graph theorem* tells you that a closed operator whose domain is the entire Hilbert space is continuous.

Why are adjoints always closed operators? Let $B:D(B)\to H$ be linear and $B^*:D(B^*)\to H$ its adjoint. Let $x_n\in D(B^*)$ and $x_n \to x$ and $B^*x_n\to y$. $B^*$ is closed if and only if $x\in D(B^*)$ and $y=B^*x$. Well for any $z\in D(B)$ you have:
$$|u(Bz,x)|=|\lim_n u(Bz,x_n)| = |\lim_n u(z, B^*x_n)|=|u(z,y)|≤\|z\|\,\|y\|$$
thus $x\in D(B^*)$. Further for any $z\in D(B)$:
$$u(z, B^* x_n -B^*x) = u(Bz,x_n-x)\to0$$
since $D(B)$ is dense and we have assumed $B^*x_n$ to converge in norm, this shows that $B^*x=y$, thus giving us that $B^*$ is closed.

Comment: what means $D(B)$, domain or something else?

Comment: Yes, $D(B)$ is the domain of the linear map $B$. The space $D(B^*)=\{ x\mid \text{there exists a }C\in \Bbb R \text{ so that } |u(Bz,x)|≤C\|z\| \text{ for all }z\in D(B)\}$ is the domain of the adjoint operator.